# How to Stop a user from passing the login page if their info is not correct IOS

Tags: ios, mysql, swift, flask, swiftui

In my IOS app, I'd like to send a message to a user who tries to login with bad credentials and notify them of this with a pop up. Currently, My database can recognize a login error but my swift code doesn't see the error condition until after it dismisses the login page and enters the app.

The flask/python code that accesses the database looks like this:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="localhost", user="root", passwd="Pass", database = "events")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        mycursor = mydb.cursor()
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']

        mycursor.execute('SELECT* FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s', (username, password,))
        account = mycursor.fetchone()

        if account:

            try:
                mydb.commit()
                mydb.close()
            except e:
                # Rollback in case there is any error
                print("Error: ", e)
                mydb.rollback()

            return make_response("Success!", 200)
        else:
            return make_response("username/password combination dne", 500)
```

The swiftui code that contacts the data base inside my app looks like this:

```
struct LogInView: View {

    @State var username: String = ""
    @State var password: String = ""
    @State var email: String = "test@gmail.com"
    @Binding var didLogin: Bool
    @Binding var needsAccount: Bool
    @State var errorString: String = ""


    func send(_ sender: Any, completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "http://localhost/login")! as URL)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

    self.username = "\(self.username)"
    self.password = "\(self.password)"
    self.email = "\(self.email)"

    let postString = "username=\(self.username)&password=\(self.password)&c=\(self.email)"

        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { data, response, error in


            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(String(describing: error))")
                //put variable that triggers error try again view here
                self.didLogin = false
                self.errorString = String(describing: error)
                completion(self.errorString)
                return
            }else{
                self.didLogin = true
                completion(String(describing: error))
            }

            print("response = \(String(describing: response))")

            let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")

            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                self.errorString = String(httpResponse.statusCode)

            }


        }
        task.resume()


    }


    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Spacer()
            WelcomeText()
            UserImage()
            TextField("Username", text: $username)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.lightGray))
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            SecureField("Password", text: $password)
                .padding()
                .background(Color(.lightGray))
                .cornerRadius(5.0)
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            Button(action: {
                self.send((Any).self){ array in
                    self.errorString = array
                }/*
                    if self.errorString == "500"{
                        self.didLogin = false
                    }
                    else{
                        self.didLogin = true
                    }
                }*/
            },
                label: {Text("LOGIN")
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .padding()
                .frame(width: 220, height: 60)
                .background(Color.orange)
                .cornerRadius(15.0)})
                .shadow(radius: 5)
                .padding(.bottom, 10)
            Button(action: {
                self.needsAccount = true
            }, label: {Text("Not a member yet? Sign up here")})
            Spacer()
        }.padding().background(Color.white).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
}
```

ContentView:

```
import SwiftUI
import Mapbox
import CoreLocation

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var annotationsVM: AnnotationsVM //= AnnotationsVM()
    @ObservedObject var VModel: ViewModel //= ViewModel()
    @ObservedObject var locationManager: LocationManager //= LocationManager()
    @ObservedObject var data: DataFetcher
   // @ObservedObject var mapViewCoordinator = MapViewCoordinator()

    init() {
          let vm = ViewModel()
          VModel = vm
          annotationsVM =  AnnotationsVM(VModel: vm)
          locationManager = LocationManager()
          data = DataFetcher()
      }


    var userLatitude: CLLocationDegrees {
        return (locationManager.lastLocation?.latitude ?? 0)
     }

     var userLongitude: CLLocationDegrees {
        return (locationManager.lastLocation?.longitude ?? 0)
     }

    var lat: Double {
        return (VModel.lat ?? 0)
    }
    var long: Double {
        return (VModel.lon ?? 0)
    }

    var Userlat: Double {
           return (VModel.userLatitude)
       }
       var Userlon: Double {
           return (VModel.userLongitude)
       }

    //@State var searchedLocation: String = ""
    @State private var annotationSelected: Bool = false
    @State private var renderingMap: Bool = true
    @State private var searchedText: String = ""
    @State private var showResults: Bool = false
    @State private var events: [eventdata] = []
    @State private var showMoreDetails: Bool = false
    @State private var didLogin: Bool = false
    @State private var needsAccount: Bool = false
    @State private var selectedAnnotation: MGLAnnotation? = nil


var body: some View {

        VStack{
            ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .leading, vertical: .top)){



                MapView(annotationSelected: $annotationSelected, renderingMap: $renderingMap, visited: $annotationsVM.visited, showMoreDetails: $showMoreDetails, selectedAnnotation: $selectedAnnotation, VModel: VModel, locationManager: locationManager, aVM: annotationsVM, data: data, annos: $annotationsVM.annos)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)

                if showResults == true && searchedText.count >= 1 {
                    Text("").frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 0, maxHeight: .infinity).background(Color.white).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    //this is pretty ghetto but whatever
                }

                VStack{
                    HStack(alignment: .top){

                        if showResults == false {
                            SettingsButton()
                        }

                        Spacer()

                        SearchBar(annotation: annotationsVM, VModel: VModel, searchedText: $searchedText, showResults: $showResults, showMoreDetails: $showMoreDetails)
//                        SearchBar(annotation: annotationsVM) { sender in
//                            self.searchedLocation = sender.searchText.text
//                        }

                        Spacer()

                        if showResults == false {
                            MessageButton()
                        }

                    }.padding()

                    //Update Annotation Button
//                    Button (action: {
//                            let delayInSeconds = 1.5
//                            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + delayInSeconds) {
//                                self.annotationsVM.addNextAnnotation(address: "22 Sunset Ave, East Quogue, NY")
//
//                                print("\(self.annotationsVM.annos)")
//                                print("User Coords: \(self.VModel.userLatitude), \(self.VModel.userLongitude)")
//                            }
//                    }, label: {Text("Press to update annotation")})

                    if showResults == true && searchedText.count >= 1 {
                        SearchResults(VModel: VModel, annotation: annotationsVM, showResults: $showResults, searchedText: $searchedText)
                    }

                    Spacer()

                    HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                        if renderingMap {
                            Text("The Map is Rendering...")
                        }
                    }

                    //Side Note: If the Create Event Button is pressed, the currently selected annotation is unselected, so that'll need to be fixed
                   HStack(alignment: .bottom) {
                         if annotationSelected {
                             CreateEventButton(annotation: annotationsVM, annotationSelected: $annotationSelected)
                         }
                     }.padding()
                }
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        if annotationsVM.annotationPlacementFailed == true {
                            AnnotationPlacementErrorView(annotationPlacementFailed: $annotationsVM.annotationPlacementFailed, annotation: annotationsVM, searchedText: $searchedText)
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    HStack{
                        Spacer()
                        if self.showMoreDetails == true {
                            MoreDetailsView(searchedText: $searchedText, showMoreDetails: $showMoreDetails, selectedAnnotation: $selectedAnnotation)
                            //Instead of passing in searchedText, we need to pass in the mapView...idk how though
                        }
                        Spacer()
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
                if self.didLogin == false {
                   LogInView(didLogin: $didLogin, needsAccount: $needsAccount)
               }

               if self.needsAccount == true {
                   SignUpView(didLogin: $didLogin, needsAccount: $needsAccount)
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is a database//server issue or swiftui/httpresponse issue. Any insight is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

how does it dismiss the login page? assuming you use didLogin to check, you should default `didLogin` to false. so the user is not logged in until `didLogin = true`, meaning it will wait till you get a response from your http request. something like this:

```
@State private var didLogin: Bool = false

if didLogin {
  ShowSomeViewAfterLogin()
} else {
  ShowLogin()
}
```

Comment: didLogin is initialized as false in content view and then passed into the login view. I don't know how didLogin becomes true even when a login error occurs

Comment: thats odd, a couple of questions. what does your `completion` do? and can you add ContentView code to the question

Comment: the completion is just to update the errorString variable asynchronously

Comment: bit confused on your ContentView. how come theres no else block for if self.didLogin == false? thats where all your app views should be in.

Comment: there is no else block because I only want the view to display if the user isn't logged in(didLogin == false). The view should disappear if didLogin == true which does happen. The problem is that even when I enter Incorrect login credentials and receive an error from the server, didLogin is set to true even though it shouldn't be